# Is it possible to import alamofire in other libraries?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I am installing below pods

`pod 'Alamofire'`,
`pod 'SwiftyJSON'`,
`pod 'iOSPhotoEditor'`

and its installed successfully but now issue is that in iOSPhotoEditor there is one swift file named `PhotoEditor+Controls.swift` in this file I am trying to `import Alamofire` but i am not able to import `Almofire` and `SwiftyJSON`

then its can't imported then I am trying second method for API Calling with `JSONSerialization` but i am not getting response success I do debug and but I can't getting response let me show you my code which I have tried using `JSONSerialization` below is my code

```
let todosEndpoint: String = "URL"
        guard let todosURL = URL(string: todosEndpoint) else {
            print("Error: cannot create URL")
            return
        }
        var todosUrlRequest = URLRequest(url: todosURL)
        todosUrlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
        let newTodo: [String: Any] = ["user_id": u_ID!, "access_token": A_Token!, "image_file": imgString1]
        let jsonTodo: Data
        do {
            jsonTodo = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: newTodo, options: [])
            todosUrlRequest.httpBody = jsonTodo
            print(jsonTodo)
        } catch {
            print("Error: cannot create JSON from todo")
            return
        }
```

How to import Alamofire in iOSPhotoEditor file so I can easily achieve my requirement with `Alamofire`

Comment: anyone have solution for my issue then please tell me

Comment: "but i am not able to import Almofire and SwiftyJSON" What happens if you try? I’m unable to understand your third paragraph. Can you please try to improve your phrasing?

Comment: if i try to import than its give me error `No such module 'Alamofire'`

Comment: iOSPhotoEditor seems to be a 3rd party library, why are you modifying it? Why not do the changes in your own code?

Comment: i want edited image and that image i am getting on `PhotoEditor+Controls.swift` button click so for that i want to pass image as parameters to send in server thats why i am modifying

Comment: But that is your own file right and the question is incorrectly formulated because you are _not_ modifying the library, right? Anyway I think you should re-consider your design because having server communication code in some button clicked method is not the best solution.

Comment: file which i am editing is file of library file and on that file there is one button and on button click i am getting edited image and than i am calling api on button click to pass image to server

Comment: Please tell me if anyone have solution